# Making windows shortcut(started by accelerate keys) start from currently active directory

Tags: windows, shortcut, keyboard-shortcuts

What I need is quite usual, which goes like this:

On a windows OS(in my case, win7), we can create a shortcut for a certain program(e.g. `*.exe, *.bat` ...), and then use right-click to bind an accelerate keys combo for this shortcut.

So I created a `.bat` file for starting my python.exe in cmd mode, then created a `shortcut` for this .bat and added  <kbd>ctrl</kbd>  +  <kbd>alt</kbd>  +  <kbd>Num 9</kbd> for it in order to start python more conveniently.

So far this works, but it always starts python with default directory:

`C:\windows\system32`.

I  wish that it could start exactly from the currently active folder's directory(e.g. if I'm in `D:\certain_python_modules\module_1` and input this key-board-shortcuts, I need that in python, `os.getcwd()` prints exactly the same directory), what  should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not really clear what you're doing and want to do.

1. There's no global currently active folder, every process has its current folder (it's called current directory). It can be programmatically specified when you launch a process, and it can be changed after its launch, but by default it is inherited by the calling process.
2. Specifically, every command prompt has its own current folder
3. When you press your  <kbd>ctrl</kbd>  +  <kbd>alt</kbd>  +  <kbd>Num 9</kbd> sequence it is detected by the shell, and the shell executes the shortcut (a.ka. as link) that is associated with it. The program that you were currently working with is completely ignored. The current directory of the process launched is set to either:

   - The 'From' field in the shortcut's property sheet, if it is set
   - The shortcut's file location, otherwise

---

When you say *I'm in D:\certain_python_modules\module_1*, do you mean in a command prompt or in an explorer/file explorer window ?

Either way, you can't do what you want with any standard Windows feature, you could probably do it with some work (maybe even not much, I don't know) with something like AutoHotKey or a program of your own.

---

If you are working in a command prompt though you can do a thing analogue to what you're trying by using a command rather than a keyboard shortcut: either:

- type the full path of the program,
- or add the command's directory to your PATH environment variable and type its name,
- or, if the program's name is long and you want to type less, make a batch file that just calls your program, give it a short name (e.g. py.bat), and add the batch file's directory to your PATH variable.

Whatever of these methods you use to call it, the called program (python, in your case) will have its current directory set to the the directory from where you're calling it.

Comment: thanks, to be short, what I want is to launch python in cmd mode from a particular directory by shortcut( I know we can launch cmd from a particular path in a folder explorer by alt + shift + f + w, and then type python to start). So if I could achieve this by alt + shift + p or whatever would just save me a little time xD.

Comment: You are not really explaining yourself, but I think understood and the answer is what I wrote above: *you can't do what you want with any standard Windows feature, you could probably do it with some work (maybe even not much, I don't know) with something like AutoHotKey or a program of your own* .

Answer (score 0):

you could use os.getcwd() method in os module of python and then, use os.system()
to give system command to change your directory
it is kind of an indirect approach though.
Hope it helps

Comment: I think I didn't well explain my problem. What I need is when I enter the shortcut-keys for starting python from a certain directory, I need the python's current directory to be the same(the getcwd()  method) rather than the shortcut's default directory. This will makes testing python module easier, which means I don't need to start cmd from a certain directory and then type python to enter python cmd mode.